# PHP Warning: Unknown: Error occured while closing statement in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

Anyone know what actually happened if see this error message?

**PHP Warning:  Unknown: Error occured while closing statement in Unknown on line 0**

The scripts work fine in my local computer, but when I uploaded it to my web hosting, I saw this error message in my error_log.

Comment: Server Info? Code snippet of anything around line 0 you think could be an issue?

Comment: i run it as cron-job, php-cli -c /path/to/php.ini -f script.php , it run every 10 minutes, but i just received 2 error logs out of 6 executions in an hour.

Comment: Jo Albright: where is line 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shot in the dark - you uploaded it in binary mode instead of ascii mode.

Comment: would be better placed as a comment, just so you don't shoot anyone by accident