# PHP/MySQL: Error occurred while closing statement

Tags: php, mysql

Got an interesting error today. I have a query like

```
$query =    $db->prepare("UPDATE XXX SET Name = ? WHERE id = ?");
```

but I get an error

> main(): Error occurred while closing statement in /home/XXX/public_html/FILE.php on line 152

Line 152 is the above code.

I was having issues of the MySQL instance no longer existing so I would add the following code above my queries

```
if (!$db->ping){
    $db = new mysqli($databaseDetails['Host'],$databaseDetails['User'],$databaseDetails['Pass'],$databaseDetails['Name']);
}
```

What is causing this error? This does not happen every time, just occasionally.

Edit: This is not because of the file's binary/ascii mode.. otherwise it would show an error on Line 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: Unknown: Error occured while closing statement in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073501/php-warning-unknown-error-occured-while-closing-statement-in-unknown-on-line-0)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't think this is a duplicate, that question and accepted answer would not allow this specific error as it wouldn't be able to recognize line 152

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: This is not Line 0 and the issue only sometimes happens meaning it is an error with my query somehow

Comment: Oh, good point on the line number, as soon as I see a closing statement error, I assume a binary mode issue.

Comment: what does your execute statement look like?

Comment: @i-man: It shouldn't even matter.. it's failing before it gets to that point